# Pulseaudio not working with jack even after installing pulseaudio-module-jack

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, ubuntu-studio, jack

Using Ubuntu Studio 17.04, I have been trying to get pulseaudio to work with jack so I can play audio from a browser while using other applications such a pure data, and followed the tutorial here putting the proper startup script into qjackctl. My jack connections are now as follows:
[image]

However, browser audio still does not work when jack is started, mainly Youtube videos do not play. Is there still something else that needs to be done here?

Answer (score 0):

browser video is probably not playing because sound is still trying to be directed to sound card rather than through JACK

Open Pulseaudio Volume control to playback tab. There should be drop-down box to switch sound playback to Pulseaudio JACK Sink

[image]